# If a particle is performing simple harmonic motion and the speed of particle is increased then how it's gonna effect it's angular velocity?

Tags: oscillators

The question was A particle is performing SHM and it's speed is tripled at some distance, find the new amplitude?
So, while solving the question my teacher said, angular frequency won't change when speed is tripled but am kind of confused as angular frequency depends on Time period, and more the velocity,less time will be taken by the article to cross a particular point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular frequency $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ which is fixed for a given spring mass system.
When you tripling velocity/speed it just means you are adding more Kinetic Energy in SHM.

Kinetic Energy depends on amplitude of oscillation thus is going to increase.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here is probably due to the same symbol $\omega$ being used for two different things.

If a particle is moving at a distance $r$ from its point of rotation at a speed $v$ perpendicular to the line joining the body to the point, then the angular speed is given by $v=r\omega$.

The defining equation for shm, $\ddot x = - \omega^2 x$, has an $\omega$ in it which is a constant which depends on parameters connected with the system which does not include velocity.

The time period of shm oscillations might depend on $k$ and $m$ for a spring-mass system, $l$ and $g$ for a simple pendulum etc if the amplitude of the oscillations are small.
You will note that these parameters do not depend on velocity.
The maximum velocity during shm is given $A\omega$ where $A$ is the amplitude of the motion, thus increasing the velocity will increase the amplitude of the motion but as stated before, not the constant of motion $\omega$.